# Loading excel files in observablehq

Tags: exceljs, observablehq

Observable has a built-in method for loading excel files. The docs say it's based on [exceljs](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs).

However, since it appears to be a cut-down version, I wanted to use exceljs directly.

I created [this notebook](https://observablehq.com/@75aecdc67c9c3e41/excel-mysteries).

Strangely, the loading seems to work - I see nontrival data in the object explorer - but access to the sheets from another observable cell gives me an empty array of sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to work with [...wb.worksheets]